# Performant way to get large list of files with modified date and size

Tags: php, performance, file, filesystems

I am using PHP 5.6 on Linux. I am getting a list of files and directories in a directory

```
$directory_listing = scandir($path);
```

I know I could do something similar to following to get an array of the filenames plus modified date and size.

```
$listings_final = array();
foreach ($directory_listing as $listing) {
    $listings_final[]['listing_name'] = $listing;
    $listings_final[]['listing_modified'] = filemtime($listing);
    $listings_final[]['listing_size'] = filesize($listing);
}
```

This will be slow when the number of files is extremely large. Is there a more performant way to archive this?

Comment: Probably not, because even `ls` grabs all of the data iteratively per entry (file/directory) rather than in bulk. But depending on why you're getting that information and how it's needed in your application, there may be a different way to do it that doesn't slow down the UI.

Comment: @NickCoons I'm building a customized directory listing and file viewing system.

Comment: What you may want to do is to get the original directory listing and send that to the UI for the user to see, and then in the background asynchronously populate the metadata (like the timestamp and size).

Comment: @NickCoons I'm not clear on what you mean. You mean do a `file_get_contents()` for the URL of the directory listing?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but since `scandir()` loads the entire directory listing into the memory in one go, it might be more performant to use `opendir()` and then loop through `readdir()`. You'd have to try both out on a folder with a large number of files to see which method is faster.

Comment: What I mean is to just get the directory listing without the metadata, show that to the user and let them use the app so they aren't waiting. Then, in the background, begin looping and grabbing the metadata then populating it into the app.

Comment: @NickCoons yes, that would work as a practical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not likely.  In accessing the filesystem, the metadata for each file is grabbed per file, not in bulk.  Even relatively low-level tools like `ls` do it this way.  So if you have 10,000 files in a directory, there's not going to be any way around making 10,000 separate calls to grab the metadata for all of the files.  There may be some tool that purports to get it all in one go, but it's just going to be abstracting the fact that it's looping through all files in a directory to get the information, and isn't going to be any faster.

The only way I know of to do this would be to create something that accesses the filesystem directly for this information.  However, that would not be recommended, as it makes your application then dependent on specific filesystems (i.e. ext4).

Your best bet is going to be to grab the initial file listing for the directory and populate that, since that can be done quickly.  Then, asynchronously, grab the metadata for each file and populate your application.  This way, the user can begin interact with your application without having to wait for all of the metadata to load.